# Ways to append to GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a webapp that goes and makes some webgets and returns the results in `Gridview`. Sometimes, the app may need to make 400+ webgets, but only populate the grid with 15-20 records.

Is there a way to partially load a `GridView`, so that each record is appended to the existing `GridView`?

**Adding Code**

```
    List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
    foreach (Location str in list)
        {
            string url;
            try
            {
                url = "http://www.test.com/" + str.Url;

                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);

                Rss10FeedFormatter formatter = new Rss10FeedFormatter();
                if (formatter.CanRead(reader))
                {
                    formatter.ReadFrom(reader);
                    IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> items = formatter.Feed.Items;

                    int itemCt = 1;
                    foreach (SyndicationItem item in items)
                    {
                            Test test = new Test();
                            test.Name = item.Name;
                            test.City= item.City;

                            testList.Add(data);


                            //if I add this here, the RowDatabound does not fire, if I take out, it works fine but only after all requests are made
                            listGrid.DataSource = temp;
                            listGrid.DataBind();


                    }
                }
                else
                    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid RSS 1.0 feed at " + FeedUrl.Text.Trim());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate list that you will DataBind the gridview to, and then whenever you change the elements in that list just rebind the gridview.

```
var mySmallerList = bigList.Skip(someNumber).Take(someOtherNumber);
myGridView.DataSource = mySmallerList;
```

Comment: I have tried something similar to that, but the RowDataBound of the Grid never fires because the process is still running

Comment: Can you spin off another thread to databind it? (I'm dumb because this then wouldn't be running on the gui thread)
Alternatively, spin off a thread to do the other work, databinding on the gui thread.

Comment: I have tried spinning up a quick thread, but get errors regarding binding to the grid during the databound process. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you would have to bind on the GUI thread instead, but you could do whatever other operations you are saying are holding up your databinding event in another thread.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are saying. Can you post a small sample?

Comment: You can't really do much GUI wise with a Thread or BackgroundWorker since said thread is not on the same thread as the GUI. You'd have to use a MethodInvoker. Here's a simple example: progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar1.Value = 95; }));

Comment: Sorry, still not following. How would I plug a MethodInvoker into my example?